# creating a named host for virtualbox accessible from host

Tags: virtualbox, hostname

For my dev machine, I have windows 7 host with ubuntu guest. I run the guest as the server.

Every time I want to test from the host, I find my current guest IP address, and connect via that (for example, today it is 192.168.1.188:3000/). Of course, this changes every time I  connect to a different network.

I want to create a named address, dev.myapp.com that I can connect to from the host windows machine, or possibly any machine on the network (if that is possible, though it may be a security concern, somebody on the network would need to know my url name in order to access, so I'm not that concerned).

I've tried chaning the `etc/hosts` in ubuntu to include

```
127.0.0.1:3000 dev.myapp.com
```

but unfortunately, this isn't resolving from either the host or guest. 
I'm using a bridged network adapter, promiscuous mode is deny.

Comment: Why does the guest not have a static IP?

Comment: @RandolphWest, should I be setting a static ip? I thought dynamic was the standard as I'm regularly switching from one network to another.

Comment: Ah, no that's fine. Ignore me :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) to fix this.

Ubuntu is using this by default via [Avahi](http://avahi.org/wiki/AboutAvahi).

The Windows host needs an Avahi-client for it to discover other Avahi-services. If your host already uses some Apple software this is probably already there via a service called Bonjour. However, if this is not already installed then a small version of Bonjour is available for download here: [Bonjour Print Services](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999). After installation you should be able to access your guest via .local.

**Note:** The mDNS system seem to use the .local postfix by default. So, if your hostname is "dev.myapp.com", then the actual hostname will be "dev.myapp.com.local".